# How to get the '{element:}' value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called `player` and the `console.log(player);` displays to me `e.fn.e.init {element: undefined}` or `e.fn.e.init {element: iframe}`.

How may I select the undefined or iframe from this variable to check with an `if` statement?

```
if(player != iframe) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
console.log(player.element);
```

`{}` is showing you the structure of the object.  You can use normal dot notation.